# How to solve project screen issue using spacedesk?

Tags: networking, window

I am using spaceDesk to project one laptop screen to another. The server laptop is windows 8.1 and host is win 8. I am able to make a connection. However when i try to duplicate screens from display setting it does not allow. It gives a message display setting could not be saved. How ca i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the selected resolution in client (Personal View/Basic View settings) is the same screen resolution as your server laptop to make desktop duplication work.

In case you encounter other issues with spacedesk, please contact us in our suppport page http://spacedesk.ph/contact/.